# Is Russia on the rise to become the new economic world power? Is the war situation paving a way towards it?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, geopolitics, western-world, vladimir-putin

I want to understand the current stance of Russia & its future economic leadership potential. After listening to the speech by Putin at the recent Valdai Discussion Club ([transcript attached](https://valdaiclub.com/events/posts/articles/vladimir-putin-meets-with-members-of-the-valdai-club/?sphrase_id=1416128)), I've been curious about the general and/or experts' perception of Russia 's standpoint. Is there a possibility that there'll be a shift in new world order, changing the economic status quo dominated by the West? Is Russia really on the rise to become the new economic power? Is the war paving the way towards it? If yes, how?

Comment: At the current pace of territorial advances, Russia would take a very long time to gain world dictatorship, so I don't really believe in it. But maybe they do. It's not impossible.

Comment: Clearly this "Could it be" is primarily opinion based and can't be answered based on facts.

Comment: Do check out [Putin's own statement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Vd8ogFrWU4) and whether it matches "create new world order" or even "remove western dominance".

Comment: Given the tiny progress of the Russia in Ukraine, Russia not in a position to ***want*** anything. It's powerless compared to the collective West. You should ask our governments what the collective West **wants**, not theirs.

Comment: If this opens up, I'd love to give some big picture historical reasons for Russia's general world view based on it's history.  Suffice to say, Russia doesn't want to rule the world, but it is right now a rising Economic Power with ambitions to recapture its former status as a global power, coupled with an understanding that all it has going for it militarily.

Comment: @hszmv "...it is right now a rising Economic Power..." Really? In 2000-2010 maybe, but since then not anymore. Despite huge amounts of natural resources and income from them, they did not manage to build a competitive industrial base and were only growing moderately, falling behind in many aspects. Now with their war, a lot of economic power will be destroyed and it will take years if not decades to catch up again. Lesson: military alone is not power.

Comment: @Trilarion They are still the letter "R" when we talk about the BRIC nations.

Comment: @hszmv only because people haven't changed their usage yet. I wouldn't be surprised to see BIC being talked about

Comment: BIC, BRIC, BRICS and whatever other combinations including C and I are all a political bubble gum. Their main problem is that the two main economy and population centers (India and China) are regional rivals of more or less comparable power with a lot of natural tension between them. No money, people or rules are moved in any direction because of B(R)IC(S). And even in this big picture, Russia, if included, accounts for ~5% in population thereof and less than that in GDP. And the Russian leadership right now works hard to reduce even these rather mild figures in population and economy.

Comment: Putin could have brought his country in line with Norway, but he didn't have the vision for it, the mentality is still totalitarian repression with lax corruption measures. I think Putin's savage murders abroad and the US rivalry, which is far preferred to cooperation with Russia, is partly to blame for ingrained anti-russian feelings which promote the repressive regime by not using leverage to fix it, let's hope nosferatu biden gets replaced with an internationally litterate replacement.

Answer (score 8):

Back in the USSR times, one of the clearly stated goals of the communist party was communism all over the world.

Of course, the world communism would presumably be led by the USSR.

After the fall of the USSR, these ambitions were more or less abandoned.

In the last 15 or so years, "breaking of the unipolar model" was a repeating pattern in the Russian official statements. This, somewhat naively, presumes that the other "pole" would continue to exist.

On the other hand, the Russian propaganda outlets in the same period constantly picture the "collective west" as a meaningless, pointless, future-less, spiritless, consumerism-centered and perversion-ridden culture not worth of existence. Jokes about "wiping out" the USA or other western countries started to circulate again after being pretty much extinct in the 1995-2005 period. This hints that the ideas of world dominance are expected and familiar in the Russian society.

-- as of Nov 10, the question changed profoundly so this answer is in no way relevant.

Comment: "Who threw the *valenok* at nuclear launch console!?"

Comment: @alamar exactly this type of jokes, yes.

Comment: Well they were active in that period, especially near the bombings of Yugoslavia around 2000.

Comment: Indeed they were, but the propaganda outlets were reluctant to cycle them over and over because Russia was in a state of "not attracting attention" back then. This pretty much changed like 10 years later.

Answer (score 6):

The view that USA governs the world, having full control over majority of European countries and organisations is the widely known Russian PR narrative but it is nor clear if any more obvious evidences exist apart of them condemning Ukraine invasion and uniting against. Formally they are multiple sovereign nations and independent organizations with multiple members, so the "singular dominance" is not the appropriate wording to name them. But yes, Russia does not get approval and acceptance between  them, fights against and claims that there is a single governor behin them all. So called "[lost sovereignty](https://euvsdisinfo.eu/key-narratives-in-pro-kremlin-disinformation-part-3-lost-sovereignty/)" propaganda fake.

Comment: In my opinion conspiracy theories should never be used to support one or the other view. They should be just ignored. People in power may use them as a propaganda tool, but they never define a policy upon them. At high levels they matter nothing.

Comment: @FluidCode, as long as plenty of *people* believe conspiracy theories, *governments* and other people need to be aware of them, and let this shape how they formulate and communicate policies. Otherwise they are deliberately crippling their public diplomacy.

Comment: It's pretty clear that if the US has "full control over majority of European countries" it also must be staging a _lot_ of disagreements. Under this view, the U.S. _wants_ to disadvantage its own companies by having them operate under more restrictive laws in Europe than the U.S., wants the overall economic capabilities of the group reduced by things like Brexit, wanted (though this is changing) European countries to spend considerably less than the U.S. on their military, and so on, since it lets all this happen.

Comment: This is all particularly implausible if the U.S. has long been attempting to reduce the power of Russia, China etc. on the world stage, since it all directly undermines that aim.

Answer (score 6):

Russia is certainly not *planning* for world dictatorship any time in the next decade or two; it simply doesn't have the capacity to do this to a non-acquesient world. (Except perhaps by starting a global thermonuclear war and hoping that they come out of it better than a dozen or so other countries. But even that's not likely to work.) They might *want* to do so, but that's neither here nor there since it's not possible.

Russia clearly *is* however wanting to become "dictator," or at least have a large amount of influence, on some of the countries surrounding it, as we've seen by the invasion of Ukraine. This isn't going terribly well at the moment, and many other countries in the world seem to be banding together to help stop such actions, so it's an open question as to how much further progress we see on this front in the next few years.

Russia may want more than just nearby countries; it might, for example, want to recover its previously enormous influence on eastern European countries such as the Baltic states, Poland, etc. It seems highly unlikely that Russia could develop the capability to do even this, especially now that these countries are alert to the possibility. If Russia is indeed wanting to do this, they have not mentioned it and are not likely to mention it; there's less resistance to taking cover parts or all of other countries if you do it incrementally, claiming at each step that that step is all you are looking for. (This is exactly what was done with Russia's takeover of Crimea, as we now see.)

Comment: Other countries have famously claimed just to want influence over nearby countries and gone on to try to get much more.

Comment: "But even that's not likely to work." One should probably add that there are whole books written about the implications of a nuclear world war. So, summarizing in a single line that it "wouldn't work" may be some sort of over-simplification. Nobody knows really. That probably alone warrants its own question here. Otherwise I like this answer a lot.

Comment: @Trilarion Well, I'm not exactly an expert at geopolitics, but I think Russia's failure in the Ukraine was a lesson to us all that just because someone _looks_ like they've got a powerful military doesn't mean that they do. I now have fairly grave doubts about how many of their nuclear weapons actually even work. And the response that going all out nuclear  could provoke might well be, "Russia has to be terminated now," for real. So not something I'd write off, but not something where I see any obvious route to success.

Comment: @cjs It's too early to speak of a failure of Russia in Ukraine. They might still get away with all or some of it. And their nuclear weapons might be in bad condition or in good one but I guess nobody wants to find that out. MAD doesn't work with a madman in charge. Putin just has to play the "I'm gone crazy" card.

Comment: @Trilarion Russia's initial invasion was obviously trying to take the capital and was unquestionably a failure. Their initial goal of taking over the entire country appears to have virtually no chance of success at this point. That is what I meant by "failure in the Ukraine." Russia will of course redefine goals to as time goes on in order to be able to claim success, regardless of what they actually achieve. As for MAD, I think you're going wrong with your analysis there, but that's for a different question.

Comment: @cjs I agree MAD is another question but I would define failure not relative to expectations but relative to the pre-war state. If Russia ends up owning more territory then before Feb 24 this year, one might even speak of some kind of a Russian success of the war. In general the war isn't over yet.

Comment: @Trilarion Well, you can define "success" however you like, but when evaluating the potential results of resisting Russia's threats I don't think your position of "Russia will always be 'successful' in carrying out their threats" is terribly useful.

Comment: @cjs It could be another question how "success of a war" is in generally defined, but at the very least I would say that "we only occupied 20% of our enemy's territory but had hoped for much more, it's a failure" may not be a sentiment shared by everyone.

Comment: @Trilarion No, it doesn't matter how "success in war" is "generally" defined. When trying to answer the question, "Is Russia likely to be able to do what they are threatening?" choosing "success" as "they couldn't do it" for similar previous attempts will simply lead you to the wrong answer for that question.

Answer (score -4):

Russia is poorly fit for "ruling the world" because it is located deeply inland. It is also a country of modest size, population- and economy-wise. All of which suggests its influence would be mostly confined to some sphere of influence, while interacting with other parties.

What makes multipolar world unlikely is that the rest of powerful countries are unlike Russia. They are ocean-facing and projecting their power overseas, clashing with each other.

So it seems that neither are likely in practice.

Comment: So your arguments do not hold for the country with the biggest area of all countries, vast natural resources, and coastal access to four different seas, including one of the three (depending on  the measure definitely still top 5) most powerful navies?

Comment: Other countries have their own strong sides which Russia does not have.

Comment: More pointedly asked: You do own a globe or political world map, do you? Calling Russia "deeply inland" is just ridiculous. If it wasn't for the countless, non-populated islands of Canada, it would have the most coast line of all countries, and it certainly has the longest uninterrupted coastline of all countries.

Comment: But that's mostly ice-locked coast with very few ports and no industrial or population centers located on it. None of Russian 25 largest cities are situated on that coastline. Maybe 50 years of global warming will change some of that.

Comment: That ice-locked coast has recently got some icebreakers as part of the "Northern Sea Route" project and now they're planning to use it as a faster way for goods from China. Just a week ago I heard that Magnet (a Russian grocery store chain) announced a pilot shipment over that route. This might surge major development in the area, I think.

Comment: That ice-locked coast has recently got some icebreakers as part of the "Northern Sea Route" project and now they're planning to use it as a faster way for goods from China. Just a week ago I heard that Magnet (a Russian grocery store chain) announced a pilot shipment over that route. This might surge major development in the area, I think.

Comment: Someone being poorly fit for a position has never stopped most of people (and countries, by extension) from trying to get the position. Neither it always stopped them from getting the said position. The question is not about the capabilities, but about the ambitions and the stated goals.

Comment: @Philip, this A is just a short retelling of [Dugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleksandr_Dugin#Eurasianism,_and_views_on_geopolitics)'s pseudo-philosophy. This sort of "geo-determinism" is fairly popular in Russia.

Comment: @Zeus Hey, I am not saying that Russia is in any position to actually do anything, just that the arguments brought forward in this answer have nothing to do with the real reasons and are based on factually wrong premises.

Comment: Whereas almost half of top 25 Russian cities by population are situated on river Volga and its basin, which famously drains to Caspian sea deeply inland.

Comment: @alamar And what exactly does this have to do with the ability to project power overseas? The biggest British cities are not at the coast either. Does that mean that Britain cannot have a powerful navy or project power overseas? Doesn't fit well with the facts. It is a bogus argument. Russia is not able to project power because it lacks behind in industrialisation, infrastructure, and research due to poor political decisions and ubiquious corruption, not because of its populace distribution.

Comment: Well Britain has slashed most of their industrialization and infrastructure in the 80s and is projecting power just OK. The corruption mantra just does not lead to any useful argumentation.

Comment: "What makes multipolar world unlikely is that the rest of powerful countries are unlike Russia." But why should it makes multipolar world unlikely?

Comment: Because shipping lanes make world connected and the winner is likely to take it all.